# event not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function which works fine in chrome:

```
function updateUserID(element) {
  var username = $("#viewColTasks").val();
  var currentEvent = window.event;
  if (currentEvent.keyCode === 13){
  if (username == ''){
     $("#viewColTasks").attr("placeholder", "Please enter a valid username");
     $("#viewColTasks").val("");
  }
  else{
    var text = $(element).val();
    changeUserTo = text;
    socket.emit('getUserID', text);
    $("#viewColTasks").attr("placeholder", "Viewing " + username + "'s work");
    $("#viewColTasks").val("");
  }
 }
}
```

is this not supported in FF? I have been researching and it seems something in relation to using e as the event but I haven't managed to get anything working on both chrome and firefox

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you binding the event listener?

Comment: How does it work in Chrome? Do you ever get into this if clause: `if (currentEvent.keyCode === 13){` ?

Comment: @MarcellFülöp, the js listens for an enter key hit on an input box on the page

Comment: PLOT TWIST!!! It seems `window.event` is actually defined in Chrome.

Comment: Is this horrible thing new ?

Comment: @RyanKinal  "works fine in chrome"

Comment: @dystroy unsure, I'm new to javascript practically, I just came across the event type through general research of how to create what I need

Comment: @dystroy AFAIK, Chrome always supported it. Sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a non-standard (Microsoft) way of dealing with events, which relies on the event object being available as a global variable.

If you bind the listener properly, you'll have both the event target (the `element`) and the event object available in a different way. Since you're using jQuery, you should be doing:

```
$('#example_input').keydown(function(e) {
    console.log(this); // the input you're typing at
    console.log(e); // the event object (including keycode)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's the key code you're after, try attaching a keyPress handler to the document.  Any key presses in elements on your page will be bubbled up and you can do your stuff there.

Try:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function (e) {
    alert(e.keyCode);
}
```

Hope this helps